# Cant change refresh rate on my laptop screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, laptop, settings

Im still new to Ubuntu. I set up a dual boot environment with Ubuntu 22.04.3 and Windows 11. My laptop screen goes to 165Hz.

I tried to change my laptop screen refresh rate on Ubuntu by going to the [display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg9FA.png) and trying to change them manually. There was only [1 option which was 60Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yRBA.png). All my other resolutions with other different scaling settings also only had the 60Hz option.

Then I installed all my NVIDIA drivers using the `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` command on the terminal. I restarted my laptop and I opened *NVIDIA X Server settings*.

Then I went to the terminal, wrote `xrandr` to see my display name and resolution options + refresh rate. Here's what it said:

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4096 x 2560, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 4096x2560+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 215mm
   2560x1600     60.00*+  60.00  
   2560x1440     60.00  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00  
   1792x1344     60.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x405       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I found it weird not having any option with a higher refresh rate than 60Hz.
I wrote on the terminal `xrandr --output eDP-1 --rate 165` and I had no error but still, it didnt change anything. Also tried with several different refresh rates but also didnt change anything.

I also found it weird that on my *NVIDIA X Server settings* there wasnt any option to change the resolution or any settings and I had no *X Server Display Configuration* like other people, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqLnw.png).

Here's also a [screenshot of my 'Software & Updates'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbRXG.png) showing that im using the supposed Nvidia 535 driver for my NVIDIA RTX 3050 Ti GPU.

Im a bit lost on what to do now since I searched for other posts that could have similar problems but didnt find any solution.

Would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance for any reply!